# select, crop, and save the uri an image in shared preferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

this code allows the user to select an image in his gallery and to crop it to put it in an imageview. but every time I leave the application and open it again, the image is no longer there so I would like to save the uri an image cropped by the users in the preference shared so that it is persistent .

Like implementing cele please!

Selection image:

```
permissionsCheck();
    Intent intent = new Intent();

    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), PICK_FROM_FILE);
```

crop image:

```
private void doCrop() {
    final ArrayList<CropOption> cropOptions = new ArrayList<CropOption>();
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    intent.setType("image/*");

    List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( intent, 0 );

    int size = list.size();
    if (size == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Can not find image crop app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return;
    } else {
        intent.setData(mImageCaptureUri);

        intent.putExtra("outputX", 100);
        intent.putExtra("outputY", 100);
        intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        intent.putExtra("scale", false);
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

        if (size == 1) {
            Intent i        = new Intent(intent);
            ResolveInfo res = list.get(0);
            i.setComponent( new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
            startActivityForResult(i, CROP_FROM_CAMERA);
        } else {
            for (ResolveInfo res : list) {
                final CropOption co = new CropOption();
                co.title    = getPackageManager().getApplicationLabel(res.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
                co.icon     = getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(res.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
                co.appIntent= new Intent(intent);
                co.appIntent.setComponent( new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
                cropOptions.add(co);
            }

            CropOptionAdapter adapter = new CropOptionAdapter(getApplicationContext(), cropOptions);

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Choose Crop App");
            builder.setAdapter( adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int item ) {
                    startActivityForResult( cropOptions.get(item).appIntent, CROP_FROM_CAMERA);
                }
            });

            builder.setOnCancelListener( new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCancel( DialogInterface dialog ) {

                    if (mImageCaptureUri != null ) {
                        getContentResolver().delete(mImageCaptureUri, null, null );
                        mImageCaptureUri = null;
                    }
                }
            } );

            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

            alert.show();
        }
    }
}
```

Activtiy result:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) return;

    switch (requestCode) {
        case PICK_IMAGE:
            mImageCaptureUri = data.getData();
            doCrop();
            break;
        case CROP_FROM_CAMERA:
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            if (extras != null) {
                Bitmap photo = extras.getParcelable("data");
                imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
                String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");
                myDir.mkdirs();
                Random generator = new Random();
                int n = 100000;
                n = generator.nextInt(n);
                String fname = "Image-"+ n +".jpg";
                File file = new File (myDir, fname);
                if (file.exists ()) file.delete ();
                try {
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                editor.putString("image", String.valueOf(mImageCaptureUri));
                editor.commit();

                imageView.setImageURI(mImageCaptureUri);
                imageView.invalidate();
            }
            File f = new File(mImageCaptureUri.getPath());
            if (f.exists()) f.delete();
            break;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please,  don't save image into the `Preferences`, it's not the storage for large blobs of data, save the **cropped** image to your data folder as an .jpg or .png image instead and store the URI or path to that **cropped image file** in your preferences.

Then you'll be able to check if the path is stored in the preferences and load up the **cropped** image when the application starts.

---

ok, I've checked your source code once again. In `onActivityResult()` you have a variable `mImageCaptureUri` -- save this variable into the `Preferences`. When you restart your app, use that variable to access the image and crop it again the same way you have cropped the original image.

Comment: yes i can store the uri of any image that the user selects but i want to save now the uri of the cropped image

Comment: @Anubis save cropped file to your app directory `Environment.getDataDirectory()`, then store file name into preferences, or use external memory for images if there are too many of them, `getExternalStorageDirectory ()`

Comment: @Anubis - I re-read your question 3 times. Nowhere does it suggest you have trouble with saving the uri rather than an image. Leni k understood your question just like anyone else would.

Comment: @Anubis I have made a few changes to the answer, probably this clears up things a bit.

Comment: @Eugene Kartoyev I may have expressed myself poorly, but in fact I want to save the uri of the cropped image

Comment: @Anubis, you should re-write your question. Other people may read it too and get confused. So far, I read "pick, crop and **save** an image in shared preferences". Therefore, you got the correct answer - don't save your image in shared preferences.

Comment: I edited my question but still do not know how to save the cropped image in the gallery and its uri in the shared preferences

Comment: @Anubis please, check the updated answer, probably this will work for you.

Comment: I try but the file does not appear anywhere in my device. check my question please I updated it

Comment: @Anubis nothing wrong with the code, I have just realized, that you don't have a cropped image, it's hidden from you inside the `CropAdapter` or whatever. That's is perfectly fine, save `mImageCaptureUrl` and use it later, should work like a charm.

Comment: and yet it does not work. when I select an image and trim it, when I validate the imageview remains empty

Comment: @Anubis can you print out the value of `mImageCaptureUrl` the first and the second time? If they are not the same, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: the images are saved in my external storage but are not displayed in my imageview

Comment: 1) did you check that you save the correct name in preferences and get it back? 2) did you check that you call `doCrop()` again when restarting the program and it gets the same `mImageCaptureUri` as the first time?

Comment: see yourself my code of `onActivityResult` and tell me if I omitted something